# Magento Unit tests

Tags: magento2, phpunit

When running Magento 2 unit tests via `dev:tests:run` unit I get an error. This is magento 2 out of the box.

> PHP Fatal error:  Class Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtension
>   contains 12 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract
>   or implement the remaining methods
>   (Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface::getBundleProductOptions,
>   Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface::setBundleProductOptions,
>   Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionInterface::getDownloadableProductLinks,
>   ...) in
>   /var/www/dev/tests/unit/tmp/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/ProductExtension.php
>   on line 7

Comment: seems there is no answer for this @magento do your unit tests fail as well? Reason being we want to be able to create a jenkins set up that will run the unit test before deployment, if they fail then no deployment. This is so we can create our own modules with unit test but if the core magento unit tests are failing, what can we do? Can any one recommend some critical unit tests that have to be run and how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Github ticket here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8125

It recommended to clear the var directory before running tests, which worked for me. (CE 2.1.6 on PHP7)